# NavigationController as 2nd View

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller

On my main view controller I have a button that shows a new view.

```
- (IBAction)showInformation:(id)sender {
InfoViewController *controller = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoView" bundle:nil];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:[controller view]];
```

}

On my InfoView.xib I added a UINavigationController and made the proper connections. However when I the InfoViewController loads is not showing the UINavigation as I want it to.

Currently I have this on viewDidLoad

```
self.view = [navController view];
```

And on the header file I have

```
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

UINavigation did not show you mean UINavigationController did not appear?

1 If you use UINavigationController, you need at least two views: one for the default view that appears with the controller and another that is pushed two.

I can only see one view here, which is InfoViewController.

If you use UINavigationController, you may want to use the pushViewController method.

2 If you use presentModalViewController method, no UINavigationCOntroller is needed.